# How do I get a page on my site to appear in the "video results" section

Tags: seo, google, video, google-ranking

Direct Lyrics appears at the top of these search results as a "video result" (next to an inviting thumbnail). But the page in question is just a page of lyrics with an embedded YouTube video.

My lyrics site has embedded YouTube videos on its lyrics pages as well; how can I get my site into the video results section?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will have to [include video information](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80471#creating) in your sitemap. The "more information about..." link near bottom of that page will give you the specifics on elements, etc.

If you happen to already produce an mRSS feed, you can also use that.