# How Google detects the page is a video page?

Tags: search-results, video, video-sitemap

How Google detects the page is a video page?

I test some pages with a video and markup and detailed sitemap.But I could not see any video result in universal SERP and video SERP.

But I test some another pages but I could see the video result in SERP both in universal SERP and video SERP.

Before asking this question, I completely check out this links and I didn't find anythings about my question clearly.You can just set some markups and sitemap and meta tags to help Google.But its not working every time.

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/help-google-index-your-videos.html

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156442?hl=en

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/06/google-videos-best-practices.html?m=0

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80471?hl=en#creating

[How do I get a page on my site to appear in the "video results" section](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17622/how-do-i-get-a-page-on-my-site-to-appear-in-the-video-results-section)

I need some exact factors that Google uses its for understanding the type pf page content(video).

Answer (score 1):

Using schema.org you can [tag your page as a page serving an specific video](https://schema.org/VideoObject) like this:

```
<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
 <h2>Video: <span itemprop="name">Title</span></h2>
 <meta itemprop="duration" content="T1M33S" />
 <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="http://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg" />
 <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="http://www.example.com/video001.flv" />
 <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?v=video001" />
 <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2019-04-23T08:00:00+08:00" />
 <meta itemprop="height" content="400" />
 <meta itemprop="width" content="400" />
 <object ...>
 <param ...>
 <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ...>
 </object>
 <span itemprop="description">Video description</span>
```

Comment: As you see in links, I have some pages without video markup and the page detected as video page.I know about the markups and video sitemap.My question is exact about what are the exact factors for google to detect a page is a video page.